# Web interface for Firebird database

Tags: database, apache, firebird

I currently have a Firebird server on Windows and Windows desktop client applications for Firebird databases. I want to make a web interface for the existing databases (using Apache on Windows). What free instrumentation (server languages, libraries) is currently available for the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) for complete but most welknown are :

- [php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ibase.php)
- [Python](http://kinterbasdb.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I can't see any clear solid solution for firebird on web. I have no time no desire to test the available staff - currently I am thinking about converting database to mysql.

Comment: "I am thinking about converting database to mysql"

You are kidding. MySQL is not suitable for serious applications with many concurent users fetching, editing, deleting data. For web site where 99.99% requests are SELECts it is ok, but for enterprise it will not do.

Comment: I did not mean to replace firebird by mysql. I need a readonly access to a database via browser (search and browse some data), and the simplest thing I can think of is a mirror mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Its not web based, but it is quite useful. I use [SquirelSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots)